# Blocking residual low voltage in a 12V automotive lighting circuit

Tags: lights, lexus, led

I'm having a problem on my car that I'd like to fix myself. I'm not a skilled electrician, nor an engineer, only someone with some mechanical skills. I apologize in advance, for any mistakes or misuse of electrical terms I may make. Please, bear with me and keep your answers as layman as possible.

On a DC12V automotive circuit wire, how can I block off any low voltage current coming through (say, anything under 9V), and still allow the normal 12V to go through, whenever the system on that circuit is activated? A wiring diagram would be immensely appreciated!

Thank you all for your time and knowledge!

Comment: are you saying that the high beam headlights are flickering when they are turned off?

Comment: Yes, jsotola, they flicker at all times, except when switch is on "driving lights" position. I apologize, I am looking for help with the actual problem!

Comment: If the lights claim to be for your make model of car and they don’t work, you should take them back to where you bought them. Clearly they are faulty.

Comment: there are modules that come preinstalled with the headlamps, I replaced both, but the same problem persists, Like I said, I've determined the problem to be a residual voltage coming through the high-beam wire on the circuit, pre-modules. I don't know the source of the residual signal. All I'm asking is how to block anything under, say,  9V on that wire

Comment: I'm guessing the circuit doesn't use relays, instead has a solid state control module? Probably uses a low current to check for blown headlights or DRL compliance or something. You could use relays but you'd have to have a clean input source wire, which is a catch 22. You haven't provided a wiring diagram or even the make model year.

Comment: The answer can be as simple as disabling the DRLs.

Comment: Again, all I'm asking is for a way to block off lower than 9V current coming through a 12V circuit wire. The car is a 2012 Lexus IS250, if it helps.

Comment: Are you saying that everything is as original  on your vehicle, but it has developed this fault?

Comment: Switched to full LED VLand headlights. They work ok. But for some reason, there's a low signal coming through the high beam wire on the car's harness at all times, which makes them flicker rapidly and continuously at low intemsity  light. Dont know what the source of the signal is, but I think iit can be fixed by blocking off the low voltage on that wire with a device that will block, say, anything under 5 -9V, but will still allow the normal 12V to go past, when the headlights are turned on. I dont have the knowledge as to what device I can install that'll do it, or what value it should have

Answer (score 1):

You can try this technique used when installing LED turn signal lamps. Wire a power resistor directly across your load. You can place the resistor at the end of a longer pigtail, and you may need to heatsink the resistor. But you can try a test setup with a 50 ohm resistor and without a heatsink. The resistor will bleed off any phantom voltage.